# Arcgis Add feature task got cancelled

Tags: xamarin.forms, arcgis, arcgis-runtime

We were trying to add a feature to the feature server using following snippet,

```
           // Add the feature to the table.
           await serviceFeatureTable.AddFeatureAsync(feature);

           // Apply the edits to the service.
           await serviceFeatureTable.ApplyEditsAsync();
```

It works most of the time but on rare case while adding an asset it take too much time to process and got timeout eventually gives **TaskCancelledException**, but the operation has been done as the item added in the server.

Does anybody have any ideas how to handle this situation or any thread related to this please share, thanks.

Comment: Depends what is timing out. What is running server side? On what server or cloud service? If its a long-running server script, the connection could time out - which could require adjustment either at server, or perhaps some time value set client side. If you can't fix at that level, then can you uniquely identify the feature by its contents? If so, query server to see if it exists. Or alternatively, if its a complex feature, is it possible to first send parts of it, then send a group description to create the feature itself? (I haven't used Arcgis, so my terminology might be a bit wrong.)

Comment: Check the inner exception parameter of the thrown exception. My guess is the request/response timed out.